# MySQL seems to ignore my WHERE clause with inner joins

Tags: mysql, sql

In order to display data (orders or bids) in a excel-like grid, i fetch from my database with the help of this query. In this case, the order_bid table store the lines that compose an order (a line for each item), the item table defines the price of an item, the current sale the item is displayed on, and the lot table defines the item itself (name, description_ect...)

Here is the request i make, orders are another table but the important part is that an order_bid is linked to an order, and orders are linked to a unique sale, but it seems to ignore the WHERE close, so i get a lot more results than expected (for example if a client placed a bid for lot 4 of sale 1, i would see a bid for sale 2 lot 4, and so on for all sales that have a lot number 4 (so all of them basically))

```sql
SELECT o.id, o.order_id, o.lot_num, o.bid, i.lot_id, i.sale, i.price, l.description_fr
    FROM order_bid o
        INNER JOIN item i
            ON o.lot_num = i.lot_num
        INNER JOIN lot l
            ON l.id = i.lot_id
        WHERE o.order_id = 38
```

For example i expect for a request a result like:

| id | order_id | lot_num | bid | lot_id | sale | price | description_fr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110 | 38 | 17 | 135 | 19 | sale1 | 135 | description1 |
| 111 | 38 | 21 | 83 | 23 | sale1 | 183 | description2 |
| 109 | 38 | 10 | 100 | 790 | sale1 | 100 | description3 |

but i get:

| id | order_id | lot_num | bid | lot_id | sale | price | description_fr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110 | 38 | 17 | 135 | 19 | sale1 | 135 | description1 |
| 111 | 38 | 21 | 83 | 23 | sale1 | 183 | description2 |
| 111 | 38 | 21 | 183 | 11968 | sale11 | 150 | description4 |
| 109 | 38 | 10 | 100 | 790 | sale1 | 100 | description3 |

and a lot of other lots that i shouldn't be getting from other sales
and i verified, when i request all the order_bid with order_id = 38 (SELECT * FROM `order_bid` WHERE order_id = 38) i get:

| id | order_id | lot_num | bid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 109 | 38 | 10 | 100 |
| 110 | 38 | 17 | 135 |
| 111 | 38 | 21 | 183 |

summarized: i get info from multiple sales when i'm supposed to get only from one (done using the order_id filter)

Comment: Clear your SQL query from PHP code. Provide CREATE TABLE for all tables.

Comment: Sample data, expected and actual results would really help...

Comment: Hi, welcome on stackoverflow. Please provide https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - it will help to find solution.

Comment: Your "actual" results don't appear to include the order_id column.